# using P tag in C# codes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with this: in my source i gave an `id` and `runat` to my `<p>` tag as this :

```
<p style="border-style:solid" id="p1" runat="server" > Hello</p>
```

But when i try to run this code :

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor,"" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + "")
}
```

and also this doesn't work:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor,"Blue");
}
```

Please help?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - do you get an error message? If so, what?

Comment: are you sure that your selectedIndexChanged event is fired?

Comment: have you added a breakpoint to check if they are bing hit?

Comment: Have you enabled Postback on the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your DropDownList has AutoPostback = true

To add a little: buttons such as LinkButton and Button by default will cause postbacks, but other input items like CheckBox and DropDownList do not be default.  Input items that don't postback by default will have an AutoPostBack property that can be set to true to force a postback when they are changed in some way by the user.

Without setting the AutoPostBack property, ASP.NET won't be notified that the user did something, and your events (in your code-behind) will never fire.